# How to also change UIButton Image when UITableViewCell uncollapsed using Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton, tableview

I know subject question sounds complicated. I will do my best to simplify the issue I am having.

I have UIButton in my UITableView. UITableViewCell is configured for the UITableView. Although, I am using UIButton action inside my UIViewController. I have setup a collapse/uncollapse for the UITableViewCells by simply changing the row height and with some priority constraint manipulation. When uncollapsing happens additional information appears underneath the cell. This far everything work flawlessly.

When I click the UIButton collapsed-default state, I change UIButton image to another one. And then when I click to cell to uncollapse UIButton image goes back to initial one. This also happens vice-versa. So, I am guessing whenever I change height of the row, UITableView recreates the cell so changes made prior is not showing.

Here is the related code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "FavCell", for: indexPath) as? FavCell else { return UITableViewCell() }

if let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: selectedCur),
    let storedCurrencies = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? [SelectedCurrency] {
    selectedCurrencies = storedCurrencies
    // SORT BY RANK
    selectedCurrencies.sort(by: { $0.rank! < $1.rank! })
        if selectedCurrencies.count > 0 {
             // CATCH ANY NIL VALUES AND PREVENT APP CRASHES
             let noVal = selectedCurrencies[indexPath.row].rank ?? 0
             let nameVal = selectedCurrencies[indexPath.row].name ?? "N/A"
             let symbolVal = selectedCurrencies[indexPath.row].symbol ?? "N/A"

             cell.configureCell(no: "\(noVal)", name: nameVal, symbol: symbolVal)
        }
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if collapseIndex == indexPath.row {
        collapseIndex = -1
    } else {
        collapseIndex = indexPath.row
    }

    tableView.beginUpdates()
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)  
    tableView.endUpdates()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if collapseIndex == indexPath.row {
        return 280  // When collapsed cell view displayed - Number will be adjusted after
    } else {
        return 120  // Height of initial cell contents that fits
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Below is how I change UIButtons image:

```
class NotificationBtn: UIButton {
var bellToggle = Int()
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if bellToggle == 1 {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.25, y: 1.25)             // Bounce
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "bell_off"), for: .normal)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity }, completion: nil)
        curImg = self.image(for: .normal)!
        bellToggle = 2

        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)

    } else {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 25 * 3.14/180.0)  // Rotate via 25 degree - Bell ringing animation
        self.setImage(UIImage(named: "bell_on"), for: .normal)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.2, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.5, initialSpringVelocity: 6, options: .allowUserInteraction, animations: { self.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity }, completion: nil)

        curImg = self.image(for: .normal)!
        bellToggle = 1

        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you show your `cellForRow` method?

Comment: Added as requested.

Comment: Did you update image of button in this method `configureCell`?

Comment: No, I use NotifcationBtn: UIButton class to apply changes.

Comment: I have added an answer. How do you think about it?

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the way to solve this. However, in order to get and update image of the button, I will need to trigger function inside UITableViewCell where UIButton outlet can be established?

Comment: Prior to uncollapsing I need to store that cell's buttons image (or image name will suffice) and update the button when uncollapsed.

Comment: Of course you can. Trigger a function inside UITableViewCell from cellForRowAt method to update button image.

Comment: Yes. You’re going right way.

Comment: If every uncollaps image are same, you dont need to save anything. Just check and change image of button base on collapseIndex @sc13

Comment: It is Notification Bell image. It has on and off images. Based on whether user created a notification it becomes On or Off. I understand what needs to be done, however I don't have enough knowledge to write proper handler. Created a func inside UITableViewCell (aka FavCell) like this:     
    
    func updateBtnImg () {
        let curImg = notificationBtn.image(for: .normal)
        if collapseIndex == -1 {
            notificationBtn.setImage(curImg, for: .normal)
        } else {
            notificationBtn.setImage(curImg, for: .normal)
        }
    }
How do I call from VC?

Comment: Inside cellForRowAt method, after creating FavCell, you can call cell.updateBtnImg() to use it

Comment: better way is passing collapseIndex as a parameter of updateBtnImg method to use collapseIndex value inside this method

Comment: This frustrates me. I feel dumb. I did pass collapseIndex as parameter. Based on collapseIndex value I put a function like this:     func setBtnImg (colIndex: Int) {
        if colIndex == -1 {

        } else {

        }
    } However cannot find a way to apply same image to both.

Comment: Found the solution finally. I had to pass the current image from NotificationBtn class where I do the change using global variable. Thank you for all your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You guessed right. When you call `reloadRows` method, `cellForRowAt` is called and replace the cell which you want to reload with another cell. The cell is replaced so the appeared button is another button. That's why you have wrong image for button.

To fix it, in `cellForRowAt` method, check and update your button image with `collapseIndex`. I think it will work. For example, inside `cellForRowAt`, after creating cell

```
if collapseIndex == indexPath.row {
    // Updated button with collapse state image
} else {
    // Updated button with uncollapse state image
}
```